# ssh connection refused despite PermitRootLogin yes

Tags: ssh

In `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` I changed and added the following:

```
PermitRootLogin no
Match Address 192.168.0.*
    PermitRootLogin yes
```

When I try to connect via ssh, however, I get `Connection refused`.

I know that its those lines affecting it because if I remove them and just leave it as

```
PermitRootLogin yes
```

I can connect just fine. What's going on here? It seems that SSH is ignoring the `Match` block.

Comment: Reading the [man](https://linux.die.net/man/5/sshd_config#:~:text=hmac%2Dmd5%2D96-,Match,-Introduces%20a%20conditional) it says you should define a network, so 192.168.0.0/24 (or whatever your network is) should work. But as @vidarlo mentioned, it should not return with a "connection refused". Maybe the sshd could not even start up due to config error.

Comment: @Mrwut An error could be possible. Is there any error in what I typed above? That exact block is what is in my ssh config file. I have also tried with 192.168.0.0/22 to no avail.

Comment: You can verify the config file with `sshd -T` command, if it checks out it should be fine.

Maybe you should add `Match all` to close the `Match Address` block

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Connection refused indicates that something at the TCP/IP layer (e.g. L3) stopped you, not that the sshd daemon denied your login.

This is probably due to a firewall or similar somewhere in the path. As long as you get *Connection refused* the authentication settings are irrelevant; there's no communication between the ssh server and client at that stage.

Comment: Then how come it works when I remove that block? It’s only the Match block that causes problems.

Comment: Probably because sshd fails to start due to config file faults.

Comment: Is there an error in the aformentioned block?

Comment: Check the logs of `sshd` or start it with `sshd -D -f /etc/ssh/sshd_config` to see if it manages to start.

Answer (score 2):

As pointed out by @vidarlo, `Connection refused` indicates an issue at the TCP/IP layer; there is no communication between the server and the client occuring, regardless of the settings in the config file, so this indicates a separate problem.

Using `sshd -T` as pointed out by @Mrwut, it was found that there was an error in the `sshd_config` file. The error was that a `Match` block has to go at the end of the `sshd_config` file, and not in the middle of it. This is because a `Match` block cannot be manually terminated, so if something is stated after the `Match` block that cannot be in a `Match` block, it will throw an error causing the SSH server to be unable to start.

Since the SSH server could not start, a connection to the server could not be established, and thus `Connection refused`.